# GitLab CI - Run a Job when removing a tag

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci, stage

I have many pipes to process and **send zipfile** to a cloud server *when a TAG is created*.
Now I would like to be able to *remove zipfile corresponding to a TAG* from the cloud server ***when a TAG is deleted***. So the UI from gitlab listing tags and files from the cloud are the sames.

The need is: **How to trigger a job when a TAG is deleted?**

```
remove:
    stage: remove
    rules:
        - if 'CONDITION FOR DELETED TAG'
          when: always
    image: xxx
    script: xxx
```